# Installation error R-package: CL/opencl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: r, package, opencl

I'm trying to install the `BayesCL` package from a local `.tar.gz` file (extracted files can be seen [here](https://github.com/cran/bayesCL/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) on Github; `.tar.gz` file is [here](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=bayesCL)).

As the `INSTALL` file says, I installed OpenCL.
Next, I set the library path and the include path.
I ran the following code:

```
#Library path: 
Sys.setenv(OPENCL_LIB = "path/to/OpenCL/library/files")
#Include path: 
Sys.setenv(OPENCL_INCL = "path/to/OpenCL/include/files")

install.packages("path/to/bayesCL_0.0.1.tar.gz", 
                 repos = NULL, 
                 type = "source",
                 lib="path/to/R/win-library/3.5")
```

This results in an error:

```
fatal error: CL/opencl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <CL/opencl.h>
```

I checked whether the `Library` and `Include` paths were correct.

Can anyone give me a hint on solving this issue?

Edit:

Exact paths that I used:

- Library: `C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing
  Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/lib/x64`;
- Include: `C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing
  Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/include`

Copied from the properties of files:

- `OpenCL.lib` (library): `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\lib\x64`
- `opencl.h` (include): `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\include\CL`

Comment: What path did you set for library and include, exactly?

Comment: Library: `C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/lib/x64`; 
Include: `C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/include`

Copied from the properties of file `OpenCL.lib` (library): `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\lib\x64` and `opencl.h` (include): `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\include\CL`

Comment: R packages can be petulant about paths containing spaces. Try using the 8.3-form short names instead

Comment: Took me some time to find out how to find the short path, but I managed. Does not work however. Still receive the same error.

Comment: Hm, I had a look and bayesCL is actually archived. But its configure script is taken from gpuR: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gpuR/index.html Maybe have a look at the wiki there for install instructions: https://github.com/cdeterman/gpuR/wiki

Comment: Also, try adding those dirs to your system environment variables outside R, and then restart your machine

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to install `gpuR`, so the paths should be correct, I think. `bayesCL` keeps giving me the same error, so I think I give up on it. The package is not maintained and removed from CRAN, which was probably for a reason.